# How would I code a link_to based on this href link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am looking to make a link_to based on the following href. I'm not sure how to put the `<i>` element inside the link_to.

Any ideas?

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap any thing you need inside the `link_to` opening with `do` and closing it with `end`:

```
<%= link_to '', class: 'btn btn-white btn-sm' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View 
<% end %>
```

That will generate:

```
<a class="btn btn-white btn-sm" href="">
  <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> View 
</a>
```

Note the first argument must be `''`, this way all inside of it will act as content inside an `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks! So how would I work in the controller/methods from this? 

    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) , { :class=>"btn btn-white btn-sm" } %>

Comment: Maybe this way `<%= link_to edit_project_path(project), class: 'btn btn-white btn-sm' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit 
<% end %>`?

Comment: I get an error: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "":String

Comment: Try without `''`, as you're specifying the route: `<%= link_to edit_project_path(project), class: 'btn btn-white btn-sm' do %>`?